# Second wpf window not showing up

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I just started with wpf. I want to have two windows. I did Projects -> Add Window and named it Window2. In my project explore I have MainWindow.xaml, MainWindow.xaml.cs, Window2.xaml and Window2.xaml.cs

When I tried to run the project only MainWindow shows up eventhough in Windows.xmal.cs I have it Initialized.

```
public partial class Window2 : Window
{
    public Window2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


}
```

Why wont window2 show up when I start it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be within the constructor of `MainWindow` make `Window2` appear.
Other windows will not automatically appear unless you display them.

```
public MainWindow()
{

     InitializeComponent();

     Window2 win = new Window2();
     win.Show();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about this but wasn't to sure.

Comment: If you search the entire solution for 'MainWindow', you'll see that in App.xaml.cs (I think!), it is set as the startup window.